# How to use sed command to extract contents inside [ ] bracket from a fasta header?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, character

I have a MSA fasta file and the headers are in this format -

```
GAN08245.1/5-191 cyclin-L1 [Mucor ambiguus]
LNNPLASLEQLETTVSRR-DGISEELEADLRNLGAELIQSAGILLKLPQVAMATAQVLFQRFFYMSLKEFGI
V-EIGGLFLASTHLITVYDLIIRKMKGIVPLDAFSKAYNLKNAIAAEMQILRQLGFIVHVQLPYNMINYLRI
LGLISKRAWNYLNDEPATIACAAICREQGIKLPTLPGWWDVSAT-L----------------------
GES74777.1/6-191 cyclin-like protein [Rhizophagus clarus]
LQNAILTYGQLETTPSKK-DNIPEELEDELRRLGCDFVQSAGIVLRLPQVAMATAQVLFQRIIKESLLKGH-
----------------------RRYRNNESLEYLGVFYEMKDLVIAEMQILKKLGFNVHVQLPYGMVNYLKV
LELIPQKAWGYLNDQPATIACAVIARIAQVKLPTSPPWWEAEDE-ISRHIMRLY-NLPLDELEYLKKG
```

I want the output to only have `M.ambiguus`, `R.clarus` and so on, and keep the sequences.
How to use `sed` command to achieve that? Or is there any other command to do this?

I tried using `awk`, it extracts out the names without any sequences.

`awk -F '[][]' '{print $2}' input.fa > output.fa`

Comment: `and keep the sequences` What are "sequences"? Could you post the exact output you want to get for the text you posted? Do you want to only replace only the part `[Mucor ambiguus]` with `[M.ambiguus]` and _keep everything else_? What "sequences" do you want to keep?

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of `grep` and `sed`:

```bash
grep -Eo '\[.*?\]' input.fa | sed -E 's:\[(\w)\w*\s*(.+)\]:\1.\2:g' >output.fa
```

Here `grep -o` finds and outputs only square brackets with their content from your input file.

`sed` removes brackets and replaces first word with it's first letter and a dot.

Switch `-E` in both commands enables ERE instead of BRE.

**EDIT:** If you want to replace `[Rhizophagus clarus]` with `[R.clarus]` and keep all other content it's even simpler:

```bash
sed -E 's:\[(\w)\w*\s*(.+?)\]:[\1.\2]:g' input.fa >output.fa
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's/.*\[(.)\S+ ([^]]*)\].*/\1.\2/p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n` and on extended regexp `-E`.

Match the first character and the second word within square brackets and print the result as required.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
grep '\[' my file.txt | sed -E 's/.*\[//' | sed -E 's/].*//'
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but maybe it's because you never need a pipeline with multiple sed and/or grep commands like this. That multi-command pipeline could be written as just a single call to sed: `sed -En 's/.*\[([^]]*)].*/\1/p' myfile.txt`. The OP still hasn't told us what `keep the sequences` means or shown us the actual expected output anyway though so it's a guess as to what they want to do.